# PHP Warning: require() failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, require

I have the following issue trying to run a php script :

```
/usr/bin/php /home/meet/web/online.php 0
```

And i have the following error message :

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/meet/web/wee/wee.php on line 425

Warning: require(/home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/meet/web/wee/wee.php on line 425
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/meet/web/wee/wee.php on line 425

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/meet/web/wee/wee.php on line 425
```

The code around line 425 is :

```
//require(WEE_PATH . 'weeAutoload' . CLASS_EXT);
require("/home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php");
weeAutoload::addPath(WEE_PATH);
```

I checked and the file `/home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php` exists on the server.

What did i did wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: Could be path issue. whats in `WEE_PATH` ?

Comment: I'm presuming your server is Linux, is the file name exactly what is in the require statement (case sensitive)? What is the output of `ls -l /home/meet/web/wee/weeAutoload.php`

Comment: @Devon If it were a permissions problem the error would be different.

Comment: @Devon I get "Permission denied" when I don't have execute permission on the directory, regardless of whether the file exists. Read permission shouldn't matter.

Comment: This is an OS error code, not a distinction that PHP makes by itself.

Comment: OK, fair enough, thanks.

Comment: Try `scandir('/home/meet/web/wee/');` and you will define your problem  ;)

Comment: @Devon : user is apache, the entire website is using the folder wee (it is the name of the framework)

Comment: @AlanBirtles : yes, ls -l is showing the file weeAutoload.php

Comment: @BurhanIbrahimi : inside php code ? (scandir)

Comment: /home/meet/web/wee/wee.php just before the line is triggering the error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ... my mistake

I only had to run the script after being on the same folder than the online.php file

```
cd /home/meet/web
/usr/bin/php /home/meet/web/online.php 0
```

that's it

thanks for your help anyway guys :)